# Scala function that returns requested type

Tags: scala

I have a configuration file with several properties in (mostly) JSON format

```
"SERVER_NAME": "FooServer",
"SERVER_PORT": [9999],
"DEBUG": "false",
"MAX_USERS": [1000],
"MAX_INSTANCES": [5]
```

that I'm loading via typesafe config library.     I have a wrapper class that has a get function which returns the property based on the name.    I want to be able to call

```
Config.get("SERVER_NAME")
```

and have a String "FooServer" returned to me.   Or an int, or a boolean, depending on what the value type is in the configuration.

My current get function is here:

```
val factory = ConfigFactory.load()

def get(configValue: String) : AnyRef = {
   val javaObject = factory.getAnyRef(configValue)
   //return something
}
```

which sadly does not compile.  the getAnyRef function returns whatever config value it is as an unwrapped boxed Java object, so that handles the type inference from the config file.   Should I just do a match on the type of the object?   What should be the return type for the get function?   AnyRef is the closest thing I found to an all-inclusive type.

I realize that Scala functions must specify return type, but is there any way I can get away with the really simple syntax I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` and `AnyRef` get mixed up sometimes, you can use `Any` instead and it should compile.